# How do I access the stack frame of a test immediately as its called in PyTest?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing a PyTest plugin and I want to access the stack frame of each test immediately as it's called. Specifically, I want to access the global and local namespace of each test so that I can see the objects that it has access to by name.

Currently, I am achieving this using a profile function, set with `sys.setprofile`, that checks that the name of the code object being executed by the frame matches the name of the test function about to be executed and that the event is `"call"`, indicating that the test has just been called.

I have found this method to introduce an undesirable time overhead and even to interfere with the execution of certain test suites, so I'm wondering if there's a more succinct and efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hookwrapper around `pytest_pyfunc_call`, which is the closest hook to actually calling the test function, to surgically apply (then remove) a profilefunc with a very specific identity filter.

```
# conftest.py
import sys

import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem):
    testfunction = pyfuncitem.obj
    testfunction_code = testfunction.__code__

    def profilefunc(frame, event, arg):
        if frame.f_code is testfunction_code and event == 'call':
            ctx_globals = frame.f_globals
            ctx_locals = frame.f_locals

            print('\nglobals:', tuple(ctx_globals),
                  '\nlocals:', ctx_locals, '\n')

            sys.setprofile(None)

    sys.setprofile(profilefunc)
    try:
        outcome = yield
        outcome.get_result()
    finally:
        sys.setprofile(None)
```

Because `pytest_pyfunc_call` has access to the actual test method object which will be called — along with its code object — and the `frame` argument passed to the profilefunc contains a reference to the code object being executed, we can use a speedy identity comparison (`is` operator) to limit our work.

With this approach, profilefunc will be called much less than if it were generally applied (and invoked for *every* call), and won't incur costs of string comparisons for every invocation.

When run against this test test suite

```
class DescribeIt:
    def it_works(self, request):
        a = 12
        b = 24
        assert True
```

We see our global names and locals printed out

```
$ py.test -s --no-header --no-summary -q

tests/test_client.py::DescribeIt::it_works 

globals: ('__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', '@py_builtins', '@pytest_ar', 'DescribeIt') 
locals: {'self': <tests.test_client.DescribeIt object at 0x7fc5b6d6ee80>, 'request': <FixtureRequest for <Function it_works>>}
```

In this test, our profilefunc is called 58 times.

If we wish to be even *more* surgical, we can just-in-time mutate `pyfuncitem.obj` to bring our profilefunc invocations down to just 1!

```
# conftest.py
import sys

import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem):
    testfunction = pyfuncitem.obj
    testfunction_code = testfunction.__code__

    def profilefunc(frame, event, arg):
        if frame.f_code is testfunction_code and event == 'call':
            sys.setprofile(None)

            ctx_globals = frame.f_globals
            ctx_locals = frame.f_locals

            print('\nglobals:', tuple(ctx_globals),
                  '\nlocals:', ctx_locals, '\n')

    def profiled_testfunction(*args, **kwargs):
        sys.setprofile(profilefunc)
        try:
            return testfunction(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            sys.setprofile(None)

    pyfuncitem.obj = profiled_testfunction
    try:
        outcome = yield
        outcome.get_result()
    finally:
        pyfuncitem.obj = testfunction
```

Note that in all of these, `sys.setprofile(None)` is called to remove the profilefunc both when it's invoked for our test method, and in the `finally` clause. This is a precaution, in case a bug or other weird circumstance causes profilefunc *not* to be called for our test method, and we run the risk of keeping the profilefunc active.